# Determine $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb Z_{2}\times\Bbb Z_{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The title is the whole problem, but I don't know what is that mean
and what it want me to do?

To find out the properties of $\Bbb Z_{2}\times \Bbb Z_{2}$?

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Its the automorphism group, the group of isomorphisms $G \to G$

Comment: @basket Yes, I know that. But what is determine means?

Comment: Maybe it is the flipper function (a,b) > (b,a) and identity function.

Comment: Given that your real question seems to be, what does *the group of automorphisms* mean, you might not find the answer previously given to "the title is the whole problem" (simply because you lacked the basic definitions to understand that problem).  In the future I urge you to consider what specific point you understand how to ask about, so that learning the answer will advance your understanding.  Here it would help to know the *group of automorphisms* of $G$ is itself a group (quite possibly *not* the same as $G$ itself).

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ can be thought of a vector space, over the field $\mathbb{Z_2}$. Also, group homomorphisms $T : \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ can be thought of as linear transformations (why?). Since linear transformations can be represented as matrices, we conclude that the ring of homomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ can be identified with the ring of $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

I agree that the question is a bit vague, but I think probably what is wanted is that for you to

1. Realize the maps of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ can be described by matrices.
2. Interpret the automorphism group in terms of this picture.