# all linear transformations from $\mathbb Z_2^2$ to $\mathbb Z_2^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I would like to ask how to find all linear transformations from $\mathbb Z_2^2$ to $\mathbb Z_2^2$
and how to determine which ones are bijections. Thanks for reply :) .

Comment: Please use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For the second part see [this duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002561/determine-mathrmaut-bbb-z-2-times-bbb-z-2?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

After a basis of $\mathbf F_2^2$ has been chosen,  endomorphisms of $\mathbf F_2^2$ correspond to invertible matrices in $\mathcal M_2(\mathbf F_2)$, i.e. to matrices
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix},\quad a,b,c,d\in \mathbf F_2. $$ 
Automorphisms correspond to matrices with determinant $1$, or with `non-zero, distinct`, column vectors since the only elements in $\mathbf F_2$ are $0$ and $1$. Hence the list of such matrices is
\begin{align}&\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},&&\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix},&&\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},&&\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1 \end{pmatrix},
&&\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},&&\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&1 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: Heh, I forgot that $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field...

Answer (score 0):

When you say "linear transformations", I'm going to assume that you mean maps that preserve the module structure of $\left(\mathbb{Z}_2\right)^2$ over $\mathbb Z$. Since a linear map is uniquely determined by its action on a basis (when one exists, of course), we can find all the endomorphisms of $\left(\mathbb{Z}_2\right)^2$ by enumerating all the possible ways we can map $B = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ into $\left(\mathbb{Z}_2\right)^2$. The maps which are bijections are the ones for which $f(B)$ is a basis for $\left(\mathbb{Z}_2\right)^2$. I'll leave it up to the reader to create a table.